# sqlite query for getting a value from a column containing multiple values

Tags: sqlite, sql-like

I have a simple table that looks like below

[image]

I need to find the 'ID' which has the Number `3`, so i wrote  a query like below

```
select * from IDtable where Number like '%3%'
```

it is actually returning all the `ID` since i have used `like` and the `Number` contains many values starting with `3`, how do i get the `id` which contains `3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concatenate a `,` at the start and at the end of the column and check if it contains `',3,'` with the operator `LIKE`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM IDtable 
WHERE ',' || Number || ',' LIKE '%,3,%'
```

or with `INSTR()`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM IDtable 
WHERE INSTR(',' || Number || ',', ',3,')
```

In Python, you should use a `?` placeholder for the parameter `"3"`:

```
n = "3"
sql = """
SELECT * 
FROM IDtable 
WHERE ',' || Number || ',' LIKE '%,' || ? || ',%'
"""
cursor.execute(sql, (n,))
```

Note that a normalized table like:

> | ID | Number |
> | --- | --- |
> | Ab | 2 |
> | Ab | 9 |
> | Ab | 16 |
> | ... | ...... |
> | cD | 3 |
> | cD | 10 |
> | cD | 17 |
> | ... | ...... |

would save you all the trouble of querying with a complicated string expression which may prove bad for performance.

Comment: awesome, it works, however i am trying to do this in a python,and i am unable to recreate this in  `cursor.execute`  , can you pls help